# componentWillUnmount not called in jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am getting this error after running my test. componentWillUnmount is not called. What am I missing here?

```
   expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "mouseup", [Function anonymous]

    Number of calls: 0
```

Component.js

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp)
  }

  componentWillUnmout() {
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp)
  }
```

Component.spec.js

```
describe("unmounting", () => {
    let wrapper
    let handleMouseUp

    beforeEach(() => {
      document.removeEventListener = jest.fn()
    })

    it("removes mouseup event listener", () => {
      wrapper = mountComponent(Suggestions, props)
      handleMouseUp = wrapper.instance().handleMouseUp
      wrapper.unmount()
      expect(document.removeEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith("mouseup", handleMouseUp)
    })
  })
```

Comment: in the Component.js, you seem to have a typo in `componentWillUnmout` (mount*) not sure same is present in actual code...

Comment: oh wow the typo was the cause of the error. thank you! @tanmay

Comment: glad it helped :)